# boost::beast http chunked response buffer

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I have response parser `boost::beast::http::parser<false, boost::beast::http::buffer_body>`. As i understand, buffer_body means that the response body data should be stored in the user-provided buffer. But, when i set the chunk callback on the parser using `on_chunk_body` method of parser, it seems like that the parser does not use provided buffer. In this case, it also works when no buffer provided

So, i need to understand how http parser manages memory when receives chunk? It use some internal buffer or what?

It seems like the parser uses provided buffer only for non-chunked response. If yes, it is correct to provide no buffer for chunked responses?

Comment: Yeah using `buffer_body` is notoriously tricky to get right. I **think** I have some answers up on this site or the Beast issue-tracker. I'll find it later to-night.

Comment: @sehe for me buffer_body works when i read http request body or http non-chunked response. In this cases, i get error::need_buffer for small buffers and reset the buffer to continue to read. But in chunked cases, i am not get this error despite the buffer is very small (2 bytes). but documentation says i should initialize the buffer and i can`t understand why i need to use it for chunkes responses if parser does not need that buffer.

Comment: Sorry, you're saying words, and I'm sure you mean something, but I cannot figure out what you mean. Luckily, we both speak code, so, I'll just [show, don't tell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75807592/85371). When you digest that answer, you will no doubt understand what you were doing wrong/differently.

Answer (score 1):

Beast supports chunked encoding. You do not need to deal with it. Lets demonstrate that by downloading a chunked response from `httpbin.org`:

### First With `vector_body`

To remove the confusing part:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fab3f6eef8fed4fc)**

```
void using_vector_body() {
    tcp::socket conn = send_get();

    http::response<http::vector_body<uint8_t>> res;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    read(conn, buf, res);

    std::cout << "response: " << res.base() << "\n";

    std::span body = res.body();
    fmt::print("body, {} bytes: {::0x} ... {::0x}\n", body.size(), body.first(10), body.last(10));

    auto checksum = reduce(begin(body), end(body), 0ull, std::bit_xor<>{});
    fmt::print("body checksum: {:#0x}\n", checksum);
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 00:43:25 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

body, 2000 bytes: [39, c, 8c, 7d, 72, 47, 34, 2c, d8, 10] ... [fd, 18, b0, c3, a3, d5, d1, 4c, 99, c0]
body checksum: 0xa1
```

### Converting To `buffer_body`

We need to use the parser interface because it will drive the body-reader, and we need to monitor `is_done()` on the parser.

For good style, we may replace the initial

```
read(conn, buf, p, ec);
```

with the more intentional:

```
read_header(conn, buf, p, ec);
```

We will receive `need_buffer` errors, so we need to deal with them. Then, we need to repeatedly set the body reader value to our buffer, and see what was actually decoded.

> **NOTE** Do **not** use the returned `bytes_transferred` from the `[async_]read` call here, because that will include everything from the wire, including the chunk header and trailer headers.
>
> The interface to calculate the decoded buffer bytes is <strike>atrocious</strike> *very unfriendly*. But it is what you need.

Without further ado:

```
void using_buffer_body() {
    tcp::socket conn = send_get();

    http::response_parser<http::buffer_body> p;
    auto& res      = p.get(); // convenience shorthands
    auto& body_val = res.body();

    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    error_code ec;
    read_header(conn, buf, p, ec);
    //read(conn, buf, p, ec);

    if (ec && ec != http::error::need_buffer) // expected
        throw boost::system::system_error(ec);

    assert(p.is_header_done());
    std::cout << "\n---\nresponse headers: " << res.base() << std::endl;

    size_t checksum = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    while (!p.is_done()) {
        std::array<uint8_t, 512> block;
        body_val.data = block.data();
        body_val.size = block.size();
        read(conn, buf, p, ec);

        if (ec && ec != http::error::need_buffer) // expected
            throw boost::system::system_error(ec);

        auto curr = block.size() - body_val.size;
        n += curr;

        std::cout << "parsed " << curr << " body bytes\n";

        for (auto b : std::span(block).first(curr))
            checksum ^= b;
    }

    fmt::print("body, {} bytes streaming decoded, chunked? {}\n", n, p.chunked());
    fmt::print("body checksum: {:#0x}\n", checksum);
}
```

### Full Live Demo

The demo confirms that both methods result in the same body length with the same checksum:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fc43a1eeaa2a878)**

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
using boost::system::error_code;
using net::ip::tcp;

tcp::socket send_get() {
    net::system_executor ex;
    tcp::socket          s(ex);
    connect(s, tcp::resolver(ex).resolve("httpbin.org", "http"));

    http::request<http::empty_body> req{http::verb::get, "/stream-bytes/2000?seed=42", 11};
    req.set(http::field::host, "httpbin.org");
    write(s, req);

    return s;
}

void using_vector_body() {
    tcp::socket conn = send_get();

    http::response<http::vector_body<uint8_t>> res;
    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    read(conn, buf, res);

    std::cout << "response: " << res.base() << "\n";

    std::span body = res.body();
    size_t const n = body.size();
    fmt::print("body, {} bytes: {::0x} ... {::0x}\n", n, body.first(10), body.last(10));

    auto checksum = reduce(begin(body), end(body), 0ull, std::bit_xor<>{});
    fmt::print("body checksum: {:#0x}\n", checksum);
}

void using_buffer_body() {
    tcp::socket conn = send_get();

    http::response_parser<http::buffer_body> p;
    auto& res      = p.get(); // convenience shorthands
    auto& body_val = res.body();

    beast::flat_buffer buf;
    error_code ec;
    read_header(conn, buf, p, ec);
    //read(conn, buf, p, ec);

    if (ec && ec != http::error::need_buffer) // expected
        throw boost::system::system_error(ec);

    assert(p.is_header_done());
    std::cout << "\n---\nresponse headers: " << res.base() << std::endl;

    size_t checksum = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    while (!p.is_done()) {
        std::array<uint8_t, 512> block;
        body_val.data = block.data();
        body_val.size = block.size();
        read(conn, buf, p, ec);

        if (ec && ec != http::error::need_buffer) // expected
            throw boost::system::system_error(ec);

        size_t decoded = block.size() - body_val.size;
        n += decoded;

        std::cout << "parsed " << decoded << " body bytes\n";

        for (auto b : std::span(block).first(decoded))
            checksum ^= b;
    }

    fmt::print("body, {} bytes streaming decoded, chunked? {}\n", n, p.chunked());
    fmt::print("body checksum: {:#0x}\n", checksum);
}

int main() {
    using_vector_body();
    using_buffer_body();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 00:52:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

body, 2000 bytes: [39, c, 8c, 7d, 72, 47, 34, 2c, d8, 10] ... [fd, 18, b0, c3, a3, d5, d1, 4c, 99, c0]
body checksum: 0xa1

---
response headers: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2023 00:52:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

parsed 512 body bytes
parsed 512 body bytes
parsed 512 body bytes
parsed 464 body bytes
body, 2000 bytes streaming decoded, chunked? true
body checksum: 0xa1
```

Comment: Thank you! But what about async reading with http::parser::on_chunk_body callback? When i read http using async_ functions (http::async_read_header for headers and http::async_read for body) with on_chunk_body callback, In this case, callback called every time when new chunk is available.

It is ok, but in this case it seems like beast does not use user-provided buffer. For example, in your synchronous case, you will get an error::need_buffer if your buffer is small. But in case, which i described, there is no error::need_buffer error despite the buffer is very small (char buf[2]).

Comment: I want to know, why in this case i am not get error::need_buffer error despite the buffer is very small and how beast manage memory in this case?

Comment: In other words, can you please provide example, in which the async_read_header and async_read used for reading http with on_chunk_body  callback provided where the body of parser have type buffer_body, and show how i can get error::need_buffer error in this case?

Comment: I get error::need_buffer only when on_chunk_body is not provided and not understand why i am not get error::need_buffer when on_chunk_body  callback is provided

Comment: The whole point is that you do not need the callbacks when using `buffer_body`. Of course, if you **show** your code, I can see what it is doing. I think I've written enough working code, so let's make it your turn? If you are going to ask "how to use the chunk callbacks", please make that a separate question. I'm happy to dive in there too.

Comment: sure, i am already created a separate question but this question stucks in the staging ground https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/75811628

Comment: Re: "For example, in your synchronous case" - that's missing the forest for the trees. Sync/async makes no difference:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d61d55c22e239784 If you can write it sync, you can write it async. It's the exact same code, just a whole lot harder to read.