# Read boost chunked response body

Tags: c++, boost, beast

I'm trying to read the chunked response body of an HTTP request asynchronously using Boost.

In my code, which I've copied [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75803164/boostbeast-http-chunked-response-buffer), I have already read the headers and am now trying to read the body. This is the minimal example:

```
void body_read_loop() {
    http::response_parser<http::buffer_body> parser_ = http::response_parser<http::buffer_body>();
    async_read(*sslSocket, buf, parser_, [this](error_code ec, size_t) {
    });
}
```

Don't mind the fact that this code wouldn't actually do anything. The problem I'm facing is the fact that compiling gives the following error:

```
Call to deleted constructor of 'boost::beast::http::parser<false, boost::beast::http::buffer_body>'
```

I don't understand this error, since the function being called captures by reference:

```
template<
    class AsyncReadStream,
    class DynamicBuffer,
    bool isRequest,
    BOOST_BEAST_ASYNC_TPARAM2 ReadHandler>
BOOST_BEAST_ASYNC_RESULT2(ReadHandler)
async_read(
    AsyncReadStream& stream,
    DynamicBuffer& buffer,
    basic_parser<isRequest>& parser,
    ReadHandler&& handler)
{
```

MCVE which, for me, doesn't compile on Ubuntu with Boost 1.74.0:

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
using boost::system::error_code;
using net::ip::tcp;

static void check(error_code& ec) {
    if (ec && ec != http::error::need_buffer) // expected
        throw boost::system::system_error(ec);
}

template <typename Derived> struct CommonImpl {
    net::io_context ioc;
    tcp::socket s{ioc};
    tcp::resolver r{ioc};
    http::request<http::empty_body> req{http::verb::get, "/stream-bytes/2000?seed=42", 11};

    void run() {
        r.async_resolve(
             "httpbin.org", "http",
            beast::bind_front_handler(&CommonImpl::on_resolved, this));

        ioc.run();
    }

    void on_resolved(error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type eps) {
        check(ec);

        async_connect(s, eps, [this](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint) {
            check(ec);
            req.set(http::field::host, "httpbin.org");
            async_write(s, req, beast::bind_front_handler(&CommonImpl::on_sent, this));
        });
    }

    void on_sent(error_code ec, size_t) {
        check(ec);
        static_cast<Derived&>(*this).do_read_response();
    }
};

struct BufferImpl : CommonImpl<BufferImpl> {
    http::response_parser<http::buffer_body> p;
    http::response<http::buffer_body>& res  = p.get();
    http::buffer_body::value_type& body_val = res.body();
    beast::flat_buffer buf;

    void do_read_response() {
        async_read_header(s, buf, p, beast::bind_front_handler(&BufferImpl::on_headers, this));
    }

    void on_headers(error_code ec, size_t) {
        check(ec);

        assert(p.is_header_done());
        std::cout << "\n---\nresponse headers: " << res.base() << std::endl;

        body_read_loop();
    }

    size_t checksum = 0;
    size_t n        = 0;
    std::array<uint8_t, 512> block;

    void body_read_loop() {
        if (!p.is_done()) {
            body_val.data = block.data();
            body_val.size = block.size();
            async_read(s, buf, p, [this](error_code ec, size_t) {
                check(ec);

                size_t decoded = block.size() - body_val.size;
                n += decoded;

                std::cout << "parsed " << decoded << " body bytes\n";

                for (auto b : std::span(block).first(decoded))
                    checksum ^= b;

                body_read_loop();
            });
        } else {
//            fmt::print("buffer body, {} bytes streaming decoded, chunked? {}\n", n, p.chunked());
//            fmt::print("buffer body checksum: {:#0x}\n", checksum);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    BufferImpl{}.run();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `boost::beast::http::parser<false, boost::beast::http::buffer_body>` in the linked answer. Can you edit your question and show the code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Hi @pptaszni, I've made some edits. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Not reproduced, compiles fine for me on Ubuntu with boost 1.74. So [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) needed, or that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One sec, I will provide one.

Comment: Hi @pptaszni, i've posted an mcve. This example doesn't compile for me, but was featured in the original StackOverFlow post I mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75803164/boostbeast-http-chunked-response-buffer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Nice. Copy-pasted, compiled and run without issues (response 200 OK, parser invoked 4 times). gcc 11.3.0 with c++20 enabled. Also [gcc 13.2 on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qzvWaaeWf) seems to like it. So not sure what might be the case, maybe bug in older gcc version, or some conflict between boost versions in the system.

Comment: Hi @pptaszni. I've found the problem. The wrong overload of async_read was being used. I presume since I had includes to both beast and Asio. I had to manually call beast::http::async_read instead of async_read. Thanks for the help!